# Expand vertical drop down menu on hover instead of click

Tags: javascript, css

I have an expandable vertical drop down menu that currently expands when first level items are clicked, however I want it to expand when the menu item is hovered over instead. The original script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
  $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I changed `.click(function` to `.hover(function` and this works, however I don't know if it is the best way to do it. Can anyone advise if there is a better way to acheive this? You can see a working example of the .click version of the menu on the left hand side of the page [by clicking here.](http://www.davidkneale.com/wcusa/expeditions.html) Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, consider touch screen users who can't hover, and just stick with the click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to hover is acceptable. It's definitely very readable code, which is the important thing. However, there is one issue - as Daniel comments, it'll make your menu impossible to navigate on a touch device, which means that you're making the site inaccessible on every mobile phone and tablet*. This is a very bad thing, but there are a few things you can do.

For instance, the [jQTouch](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jqtouch&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.jqtouch.com/&ei=Nf8_UK7lH7Oq0AHy6oBw&usg=AFQjCNEI--nqPC2jrRNA2tnHq78zaCHtFQ) library has some awesome touch-specific event handling that would let you optimize your menu for mobile users. Otherwise, you could wrap your menu's JavaScript logic in a conditional, or you could assign each action to both touch and click.

**except for phones and tablets with mice (a very atypical use case.)*

Comment: Argh... can't believe I forgot about touch devices! Bit of a javascript novice... any chance you could point me in the right direction as to how to assign each action to both touch and click?

Comment: You'd want to define a function with the menu rendering code inside, and then bind that function to each event: `function menu(element) {...} $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){menu(this)}).hover(function(){menu(this)});`

Comment: Or there's a jQuery plugin that can double up on events here: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/05/bind-multiple-events-simultaneously-with-jquery/